# Print custom message if Laravel phpunit test fail

Tags: laravel-5, phpunit

I'm working with Laravel and my code is like that

```
$this->actingAs($user)
    ->json('post', '/graphql/admin', ['query' => $query])
    ->assertStatus(200)
    ->assertJsonStructure($expected);
```

I would like to print the variable `$query` if this test fails.

My ideal is add in the end of code some like:

```
if ($this->isFail()) {
   echo $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file `TestCase.php` add this function

```php
// tests/TestCase.php

public function assertJsonStructure(
    string $url,
    array $params,
    array $expected
) {
    $response = $this->json('post', $url, $params);
    try {
        $response->assertStatus(200)->assertJsonStructure($expected);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $this->printDie($params, $expected, $ex, $response);
    }
}
```

And this function:

```
// tests/TestCase.php

private function printDie($params, $expected, \Exception $ex, $response, $user_id = null)
{
    $content = substr($response->getContent(), 0, 1500);
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $error = [
        'class' => static::class.'::'.$trace[2]['function'],
        'params' => $params,
        'expected' => $expected,
        'user' => $user_id,
        'error' => $ex->toString(),
        'content' => $content,
    ];
    dd($error);
}
```

Now, you can test your query:

```php
$this->assertJsonStructure(
   '/graphql',
   [
      'query' => $query,
   ],
   $expected
);
```

And, if it fail, it will print the error info, and it will easier to debug. You can see a preview [here](https://albertcito.com/blog/testing-laravel-graphql-query)